# Spring boot throws an Netty4HttpServerTransport exception during elastic search TransportClient startup

Tags: java, spring-boot, elasticsearch

I am trying to convert my project to REST based project using Spring boot(version 2). The original project  used to do text search using elastic search (6.6.1) and it was working as expected.  Then in the ‘spring boot starter web project’, I introduced a RESTController  to invoke the above  TextSearch class

Please see the relevant classes

```
public class TextSearch {
    private final TransportClient client;
    public static final Logger LOGGER = LoggerFactory.getLogger(TextSearch.class);

    public TextSearch() {
        Settings settings = Settings.builder().put("cluster.name", "elasticsearch").put("client.transport.sniff", true).build();
        client= new PreBuiltTransportClient(settings);
        try {
            client.addTransportAddress(new TransportAddress(InetAddress.getByName("localhost"), 9300));
        }catch (UnknownHostException e) {
            LOGGER.error("Unknown host exception {}", e);
        }
    }
}
// spring rest controller class
@RestController
public class SearchController {


    @RequestMapping("/search")
    public String search(@RequestParam(value="name", defaultValue="World") String name) {

        List<SCMappedData> mappedList = FetchScDataJsoup.fetch();
   System.out.println("#######no of entries" + mappedList.size());
        TextSearch textSearch = new TextSearch("legal", "sc");
        boolean indexCreation = textSearch.createIndex(mappedList);

        List<SearchHit> hits = textSearch.search(name);
                for (SearchHit hit:hits
             ) {
            System.out.println(hit.getSourceAsString());
        }
               if(hits.size() > 0) {
                   return hits.get(0).getExplanation().getDescription();
               } else {
                   return " nt found";
               }

                }
}
```

But the get request fails with following error

```
java.lang.NoSuchFieldError: Shared
    at org.elasticsearch.http.netty4.Netty4HttpServerTransport.<clinit>(Netty4HttpServerTransport.java:124) ~[transport-netty4-client-5.6.11.jar:5.6.11]
    at org.elasticsearch.transport.Netty4Plugin.getSettings(Netty4Plugin.java:55) ~[transport-netty4-client-5.6.11.jar:5.6.11]
    at org.elasticsearch.plugins.PluginsService.lambda$getPluginSettings$0(PluginsService.java:89) ~[elasticsearch-6.6.1.jar:6.6.1]
    at java.base/java.util.stream.ReferencePipeline$7$1.accept(ReferencePipeline.java:271) ~[na:na]
    at java.base/java.util.ArrayList$ArrayListSpliterator.forEachRemaining(ArrayList.java:1492) ~[na:na]
    at java.base/java.util.stream.AbstractPipeline.copyInto(AbstractPipeline.java:484) ~[na:na]
    at java.base/java.util.stream.AbstractPipeline.wrapAndCopyInto(AbstractPipeline.java:474) ~[na:na]
    at java.base/java.util.stream.ReduceOps$ReduceOp.evaluateSequential(ReduceOps.java:913) ~[na:na]
    at java.base/java.util.stream.AbstractPipeline.evaluate(AbstractPipeline.java:234) ~[na:na]
    at java.base/java.util.stream.ReferencePipeline.collect(ReferencePipeline.java:578) ~[na:na]
    at org.elasticsearch.plugins.PluginsService.getPluginSettings(PluginsService.java:89) ~[elasticsearch-6.6.1.jar:6.6.1]
    at org.elasticsearch.client.transport.TransportClient.buildTemplate(TransportClient.java:147) ~[elasticsearch-6.6.1.jar:6.6.1]
    at org.elasticsearch.client.transport.TransportClient.<init>(TransportClient.java:288) ~[elasticsearch-6.6.1.jar:6.6.1]
    at org.elasticsearch.transport.client.PreBuiltTransportClient.<init>(PreBuiltTransportClient.java:128) ~[transport-6.6.1.jar:6.6.1]
    at org.elasticsearch.transport.client.PreBuiltTransportClient.<init>(PreBuiltTransportClient.java:114) ~[transport-6.6.1.jar:6.6.1]
    at org.elasticsearch.transport.client.PreBuiltTransportClient.<init>(PreBuiltTransportClient.java:104) ~[transport-6.6.1.jar:6.6.1]
    at search.TextSearch.<init>(TextSearch.java:40) ~[classes/:na]
    at run.SearchController.search(SearchController.java:25) ~[classes/:na]
```

I know that I may have to give more details to get an answer but I am not sure what all details I have to give.

This is my first attempt to work with Spring projects. Therefore I was wondering whether someone can give a high level advice on this.

Answer (score 2):

Looking at the exception stack trace, ElasticSearch version is not matching with the netty client. So use the same version.

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.elasticsearch.plugin</groupId>
    <artifactId>transport-netty4-client</artifactId>
    <version>6.6.1</version>
</dependency>
```

Comment: Hi, It was working for me now without the above dependency. I forgot to update here. I will update with answer later

Comment: To be honest, I forgot how it got resolved but I think I was  using  spring-boot-starter as an artifactid instead of spring-boot-starter-web <dependency>
   <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
   <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-web</artifactId>
  </dependency>